# Reference of this Sanskrit quote

Tags: scripture, identification-request, shloka

I read this Sanskrit shloka in a book.

> पृथिव्यां त्रीणि रत्नानि जलमन्नं सुभाषितम्। मूढ़ै: पाषाणखण्डेषु रत्नसंज्ञा विधीयते।।
>
> Prithivyaam trini ratnaani jalamannam subhaashitam | Mudeih paashaan-khandeshu
> ratnam-sagyaa vidhiyate ||

Is it mentioned in any Hindu scripture? From where is it taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is from  [Śrī Cāṇakya Nīti 14.1](http://prakrit.info/vrddhi/readings/canakya-14-1/):

> पृथिव्यां त्रीणि रत्नानि जलमन्नं सुभाषितम् । मूढैः पाषाणखण्डेषु रत्नसंज्ञा विधीयते ॥
>
> pṛthivyāṃ trīṇi ratnāni jalamannaṃ subhāṣitam । mūḍhaiḥ pāṣāṇakhaṇḍeṣu
> ratnasaṃjñā vidhīyate ॥

~ There are three jewels on earth — water, food and wise sayings (Subhāṣita). (Only) fools call pieces of (gem) stone as jewels!

Comment: Thanks for the answer